# ASP.Net webapplication, keep in mind things for performance ,scalability

Tags: asp.net, performance, scalability, web-applications

what are the things a developer should keep in mind or should take care when depeloping a web application.

web application e.g. social networking web app.

which are the things which must be implemented to get good performance and scalability.

please provide any article or blogs or suggestions for this kind of question if you have

-thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Some things that popped up in my mind

- build in caching
- keep code clean and (unit) testable
- messure code coverage
- optimize database with indexs and check execution plans
- refactor every thing you build
- optimize front end loading time (minification, gzip, compressing)
- use source control

Comment: hi "lvo" can you please tell me how to do httpcompression in IIS7?
as well as i dont know how to do gzip and minification if u have any links for the same pls provide me

Comment: check out,  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CssAndJavaScriptOptimizer.aspx?display=Print

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate Viewstate where you don't need it.

Most important:
Make sure to hold the amount of roundtrips as small as possible. Understanding the Life-Cyclus of an asp.net website is most important for that matter.

http://www.startvbdotnet.com/aspsite/forms/formlifecycle.aspx

Comment: Or, use ASP.NET MVC and wave goodbye to bloated viewstate and convoluted page life cycles. ;)